# Cannot send data to two clients at the same time when using sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

I'm currently trying to make a socket server and client program in which the server is able to send simple strings of text to the clients. As of now even when two clients are recognized and established, the message only gets sent to whichever connected first. I've been moving around lots of my code and trying to solve the problem but nothing seems to work. My code for the server is immediately below followed by the client code. Everything works when I only connect to one client; however, as soon as a second connection is made and recognized it continues to only send to the first client while the second client stays in a waiting process. Any help is appreciated and thank you!

**server code**

```
import socket
import threading
import time

HEADER = 2048
PORT = 4444
SERVER = server ip (redacted)
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "dc"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    while True:
        comman = input("message: ")
        conn.send(comman.encode(FORMAT))

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

print("server is starting...")
start()
```

**client code**

```
import socket
from sys import stdin
import time
import subprocess
import os

HEADER = 2048
PORT = 4444
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "dc"
SERVER = server ip (redacted)
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def recieve():
    while True:
            print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))


recieve()
```

Comment: Works for me. The only thing the server sends is input that you have to enter manually. Are you sure doing that?

Comment: Hmm did you try it with multiple cleints? I'm only having trouble when I use two or more clients